# Find document libraries/document for which "Copy Link" is set to "People in Tenant with Link"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, tenant, copylink

In SP Online, how to find all the document libraries/documents in the tenant for which "Copy Link" is set to "People in Tenant with Link"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try below PowerShell script:

```
$tenant=get-spotenant
If($tenant.DefaultSharingLinkType -eq "Internal"){Get-SPOsite | where {$_.DefaultSharingLinkType -eq "None" -Or $_.DefaultSharingLinkType -eq "Internal"}}else {Get-SPOsite | where {$_.DefaultSharingLinkType -eq "Internal"}}
```